# Windows Server 2008R2 - Programs Not Installed in C:\Program Files (x86) Not in “Choose Default Program”

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

In Windows Server 2008R2 I have installed programs in D:\Program Files (x86) to keep my C: drive as pristine as possible. The problem is that programs not installed in C:\Program Files (x86) are not displayed when I right-click a file, select Open With... and select "Choose Default Program".

Is there a registry setting or some other setting that will allow these programs to be displayed in the list? The same thing happens in Windows Server 2012. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you've done this manually by specifying an installation path for each program.

If you [change the "Default Installation Directory"](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/how-do-you-change-the-default-installation/73450b25-d794-4f18-9add-75253b893343) then not only with the "Choose Default Program" dialog start in `D:\Program Files\` but also any new software will install there by default.